# Why won't my logic work for if-statements?

Tags: java, if-statement

User inputs a number and it's compared to a computer generated one... I'm trying to use if statements to determine how close the guess is to the generated one.

Comment: So, what's the problem? The only thing wrong I see is that you are missing tome else's

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Sorry, my question is it only outputs "COLD: > 50 numbers close!" no matter what the number is.

Comment: I would suggest, rather the try to work from lower to higher rangers, start at the highest range and walk down... `if (diff > 50) {...} else if (diff > 20) {...}` etc..

Comment: Stackoverflow should reject all questions that don't at least contain a question mark

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing an `else` in the chain between `diff > 50` and `(diff <= 10) && (diff >= 6)`.

Note that this is not the best solution to the problem, because you duplicated the code. Rather than having two branches for "under" and "over", make one branch, and use `Math.abs` to compute the difference.

Comment: Wow, I feel dumb. Thank you!